# Email Verificationl is not sent after registration. Django + Celery

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, email-verification

I use Windows without WSL. Recently I have installed Redis for caching in my Django project. I've done it without some problems using this link: https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases

Next task was working with Celery for registration optimization (If I understand correctly, I'm watching a development course). I've done everything as in my course. But Email Verification didn't worked.
I have the same code like author code. But author use MacOS.

I don't fully understand the work with Celery, but I need to do it.

I will be grateful for your help!

***base - root directory

users - app for working with users***

base/_init_.py:

```
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

base/celery.py:

```
import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'base.settings')

app = Celery('base')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

base/settings.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL: str = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: str = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
```

users/forms.py:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4',
        'placeholder': 'Enter the name',
    }))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4',
        'placeholder': 'Enter the surname',
    }))
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4',
        'placeholder': "Enter the user's name",
    }))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4',
        'placeholder': 'Enter the email address',
    }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4',
        'placeholder': 'Enter the password',
    }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
        'class': 'form-control py-4',
        'placeholder': 'Confirm the password',
    }))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields: list[str] = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def save(self, commit: bool = True):
        user = super().save(commit=True)
        send_email_verification.delay(user.id)

        return user
```

users/models.py:

```
class EmailVerification(models.Model):
    code = models.UUIDField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    expiration = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'EmailVerification object for {self.user.email}'

    def send_verification_email(self) -> None:
        link: str = reverse('users:email_verification', kwargs={'email': self.user.email, 'code': self.code})
        verification_link: str = f'{settings.DOMAIN_NAME}{link}'
        subject: str = f'Confirmation of the account for {self.user.username}'
        message: str = f'To confirm the account {self.user.email} follow this link {verification_link}'

        send_mail(
            subject=subject,
            message=message,
            from_email=settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            recipient_list=[self.user.email],
            fail_silently=False,
        )

    def is_expired(self) -> bool:
        return True if now() >= self.expiration else False
```

users/tasks.py:

```
import uuid
from datetime import timedelta

from celery import shared_task
from django.utils.timezone import now

from users.models import EmailVerification, User


@shared_task
def send_email_verification(user_id: int):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    expiration = now() + timedelta(hours=48)
    record = EmailVerification.objects.create(code=uuid.uuid4(), user=user, expiration=expiration)
    record.send_verification_email()
```

users/views.py:

```
class EmailVerificationView(TitleMixin, TemplateView):
    title: str = 'SyCloth - Email Verification'
    template_name: str = 'users/email_verification.html'

    def get(self, request, *args: any, **kwargs: dict[str, any]):
        code = kwargs['code']
        user = User.objects.get(email=kwargs['email'])
        email_verifications = EmailVerification.objects.filter(user=user, code=code)

        if email_verifications.exists() and not email_verifications.first().is_expired():
            user.is_verified_email = True
            user.save()
            return super(EmailVerificationView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
```

Celery response:

```
celery -A base worker -l INFO
   
 -------------- celery@S0fft v5.3.4 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         base:0x26b820534d0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://127.0.0.1:6379/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** -----
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . users.tasks.send_email_verification

[2023-11-01 09:45:19,026: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Development\sycloth\.venv\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2023-11-01 09:45:19,026: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://127.0.0.1:6379//
[2023-11-01 09:45:19,026: WARNING/MainProcess] C:\Development\sycloth\.venv\Lib\site-packages\celery\worker\consumer\consumer.py:507: CPendingDeprecationWarning: The broker_connection_retry configuration setting will no longer determine
whether broker connection retries are made during startup in Celery 6.0 and above.
If you wish to retain the existing behavior for retrying connections on startup,
you should set broker_connection_retry_on_startup to True.
  warnings.warn(

[2023-11-01 09:45:19,033: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2023-11-01 09:45:19,456: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 2600 calling self.run()
[2023-11-01 09:45:19,462: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 12996 calling self.run()
[2023-11-01 09:45:19,474: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 13852 calling self.run()
[2023-11-01 09:45:19,481: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 4484 calling self.run()
[2023-11-01 09:45:20,058: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2023-11-01 09:45:20,078: INFO/MainProcess] celery@S0fft ready.
[2023-11-01 09:47:26,420: INFO/MainProcess] Task users.tasks.send_email_verification[38683e5e-b122-45eb-914f-f718fb32f9af] received
[2023-11-01 09:47:27,021: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process 13688 calling self.run()
[2023-11-01 09:47:27,021: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 10364 calling self.run()
[2023-11-01 09:47:27,102: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 7488 calling self.run()
```

Redis:

```
redis-cli.exe
127.0.0.1:6379> ping
PONG
127.0.0.1:6379> c
```